# Break Page after 6 div using page-break-after?

Tags: html, css

Here is what my print page look like,

[image]

Here is my html glimpse,

```
<style>
    .container{
        float: left; 
        border: 1px solid Black; 
        width: 400px;
        height: 350px;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
    .container img{
        max-width: 200px;
        max-height: 200px;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <b>Name: </b>@Product.Name<br />
    <b>Model: </b>@Product.ModelNumber<br />
    <img src="@Product.ImagePath" /><br />
    <span style="font-size: 20px">DetailedDescriptions</span><br />
    @foreach(var attr in Product.DetailedDescriptions){
        @attr.Header<br />
    }
    <span style="font-size: 20px">KeyAttributes</span><br />
    @foreach(var attr in Product.KeyAttributes){
        @attr.Name<br />
        @attr.Value<br />
    }
</div>
```

How to make sure that the page break after every 6 divs using css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/TjCB8/)**

```
.wrapper div:nth-child(6n)
{
    margin-bottom: 300px;
}
```

Which means: after every 6 containers - add a bottom margin of x px (how ever much you need) so that it pushes the next boxes to the next page.

Comment: This look nice. But I prefer  page-break-XXX. So that it work with any dimension.

Comment: In your question your containers are of a fixed height - so this should work for you :)

Comment: Removing float is working but I need to float element to left so that I can place as many element in row as possible. Is there is way?

Comment: try display: inline-block instead of float

Comment: try vertical-align:middle ... not sure though... otherwise i'll need a fiddle from you

Comment: Now it's fine. But curious that how vertical-align:middle make the height same. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should encapsulate your **divs** and create a better structure of this type in **HTML**:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-holder">
        <div class="container-row">
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="container"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-row">
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="container"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-row">
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="container"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-holder">
        <div class="container-row">
            <div class="container"></div>
            <div class="container"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- keep adding more container-rows -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Then in **CSS** take several things into account:

1. let *body* take up whole page
2. use **page-break-inside: avoid;**
3. give specific width and height in pixels to *divs*
4. *containers* should have the **display: inline-block** and **vertical-align: bottom;**
5. *container-holders* should have **display:block** property
6. [bonus] avoid inline style

Here is a working **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/achudars/Brtfa/)**

I have tried it outside of jsFiddle and I get this result:

[image: print preview]

Comment: if this works for you, please mark this response as *answered*

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
div:nth-of-type(6n) {
    page-break-after:always;
}
```

to insert a page-break after each 6. div, but I think this will not work with floats.